# CocoaPods & GitHub - Getting Current Files

Tags: ios, github, cocoapods

I'm working on an iOS project using the Light Blue Bean (bluetooth Arduino microcontroller).  The SDK is kept on GitHub (https://github.com/PunchThrough/Bean-iOS-OSX-SDK) and I'm using CocoaPods.  When I updated to xCode 7 I could no longer build the app; I was getting 2 issues of properties not found (it seems they were depreciated in iOS 9).  I see someone had already raised the issue on GitHub and it seems that updates were made for iOS 9 compatibility (https://github.com/PunchThrough/Bean-iOS-OSX-SDK/pull/14/files).  I tried to reinstall the dependencies with Cocoapods ('pod install' in Terminal) thinking that would pull the new files from GitHub, but that didn't do anything.  I'm wondering if I'm using CocoaPods incorrectly.  How do I make Cocoapods grab the newest files from GitHub?  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `pod update` instead of `pod install` if you'd previously installed an older version of the pod.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify commit to get a latest version in Podfile e.g

```
 pod 'TTTAttributedLabel', :git => 'https://github.com/getaaron/TTTAttributedLabel.git', :commit => 'd358791c7f593d6ea7d6f8c2cac2cf8fae582bc1'
```

to get SHA of last commit you can use

```
git rev-parse origin/master | pbcopy
```

or
look on github commit page.

But I don't think it's CocoaPods problem. I would recommend that you install the old version of Xcode from Apple Developer download center.

And keep both versions of Xcode, till the repo that you used from CocoaPods will be updated. To install both versions of Xcode just put Xcode 6.4 to your Desktop or somewhere similar.